# How to add strings any type of string into PostgreSQL text field

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres database where I have a column that stores text. This text is user input and can have all types of strange characters empirically for example both `'` and `"`.

But in in principle there is no limit.

How can I format my update strings such that I can input them with the following query type:

```
update article
set text = <formated_text>
where article.name=<name>;
```

Comment: you should use a parameterized query. which language you are using to connect to postgresql

Comment: Thanks i'm using python

Comment: https://pynative.com/python-postgresql-insert-update-delete-table-data-to-perform-crud-operations/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two techniques:

1. use a prepared statement:

   ```
   PREPARE ins(text, text) AS
   UPDATE article SET text = $1 WHERE article.name = $2;
   ```

   Then you can call it like

   ```
   EXECUTE ins('with '' quote', 'more '' quotes''');
   ```

   and you can be sure that no SQL injection can happen.

   This example is using server side prepared statements, but your client API will provide prepared statements too.
2. properly escape the strings:

   ```
   DO
   $$DECLARE
      v_text = 'with '' quote';
      v_name = 'more '' quotes''';
   BEGIN
      EXECUTE 'UPDATE article SET text = '
              || quote_literal(v_text)
              || ' WHERE article.name = '
              || quote_literal(v_name);
   END;$$;
   ```

   This example uses PL/pgSQL, but there should be similar quoting functions in your client API as well.

If you have a chioce, prepared statements are better.

Comment: Is this also robust to "," and other signs. Sorry sometimes the strings I have er pretty wired.

Comment: Yes, that will cover anything.